# How to add files to .gitignore and why doesn't .gitignore file content change after ignoring files with source tree?

Tags: command-line, bash, git

I wanted to ignore the entire `.vs` folder because I was getting a locked/permission denied error on `sqlite3/db.lock` found in the `.vs` folder, so I created a `.gitignore` file with this bash command:

`touch .gitignore`

and then added this line inside of the .gitignore file:

`.vs/*`

But I still got the same error when I run `git add --all`.

In the end, I opened Sourcetree app, ignored the `.vs` folder content by right clicking the files and choosing ignore, and then I managed to add all the files, commit and push (through the Sourcetree app).

Not pleased with this solution because I wanted to do everything through command line. Now I am wondering why has the gitignore content not changed if I supposedly have manipulated it through Sourcetree? And how can I add files to `.gitignore`? What I did didn't seem to have any effect (the fact that I added line `.vs/*`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did had an effect. Namely that all **future** changes will be ignored.

The issue here is that when you add files to `.gitignore` they will be ignored from any changes you make but they will still remain in the repository. What you need to do is remove everything from git and add them again. This way the files you want ignored won't be added.

You can do this with the following commands:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m ".gitignore fix"
```

Reference: http://www.codeblocq.com/2016/01/Untrack-files-already-added-to-git-repository-based-on-gitignore/

Comment: That's great, thanks you! I thought I had tried that before but maybe not in the right order. So the commit finally got pushed and all well but ... except for the few (about 4) files I have changed, actually no less than 37 files got pushed to the server (a number of cache, pdb, dll, xaml files, basically everything from bin/Debug and obj/Debug). Shouldn't these files be ignored at commit?  The point of having various commits was to observe the few required/relevant changes matching some (sometimes) minor requests... if I examine my last commit I get lost in all the debug files

Comment: Add all the debug paths to gitignore one by one manually would be far from ideal (I have many projects). PS. I already tried adding two lines `bin` and `obj` to `.gitignore` - it doesn't help.

Comment: Yeah I'm not familiar with some of the tools you are using but it seems like those files should be ignored. If you added it to the `.gitignore` after adding the files and then followed the instructions I gave the files will still be in the commit history so some commits will contain them. However, the latest commit wouldn't have them. Are you sure you added them to the `.gitginore` properly? If so please update your question and list the files you wanted ignored (full path from project root) and the relevant `.gitignore` entries. If it's an open source project I could look at the repo for you?

Comment: This is my .gitignore content, just 3 lines: `.vs/*` on one line, 
`bin` on the next and `obj` on the last.  ShopViewer.View/bin/Debug/ShopViewer.Presentation.dll is one of the 37 files that got into the commit, even though `bin` was added to `.gitignore`, but maybe I didn't add it correctly. I'm still researching a better way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Hm that's strange. That should be working. Editing anything in `ShopViewer.View/bin/` shouldn't cause git to add the changes. Sorry not sure what's going on

Comment: It seems there is a problem when .gitignore was not added from the start (from creating the solution). I just came here to say it worked when I added the . after "cached" but just now I notice you added it too from the start! My mistake. Thank you again.

Comment: Would you know how you can add the gitignore when creating a new repository in github? I wanted to add but there is no c# option among all the available languages.

Comment: Ah okay cool! Well I usually don't add `.gitignore` files from GitHub. What I usually do is just whenever I notice a file a don't want I add it to the `.gitignore` or just Google say "gitignore nodjs" to find an appropriate gitignore online. Then simply download the file and add it to my project